# inotify or equivalent on CIFS mount?

Tags: cifs, inotify

I'm trying to use incron or inotifywait on a CIFS share but it seems that inotify does not work with such mounts (cf. http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2009-April/004319.html). Is there an alternative to be notified of changes on a CIFS share?

Comment: Not with the Linux kernel CIFS implementation, there's not. Is it possible to use a different CIFS implementation -- one that supports [NT_TRANSACT_NOTIFY_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441586%28v=prot.13%29.aspx)?

Comment: Are you referring to the client or server implementation? I'm using a WD MyBook NAS that uses Linux 2.6.24.4 according to `uname`. I am mounting the CIFS shared folder onto an Ubuntu Linux 2.6.38-13-generic-pae.

Comment: If you view a directory on one Windows machine and change it on another, do you see the change immediately?